# How to receive error if the S3 prefix is incorrect when copying files?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

If the s3 prefix is incorrect, Snowflake doesn't throw an error. Is there a way to fail the copy command with the use of appropriate parameters?

```
COPY INTO <table>
FROM 's3://<valid-Bucket>/<INVALIDPREFIX>'
FILE_FORMAT = (
  COMPRESSION = 'AUTO' 
  FIELD_DELIMITER = '\\001'
  RECORD_DELIMITER = '\n'
  ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD= NONE 
  TRIM_SPACE = FALSE
  )
  ON_ERROR = ABORT_STATEMENT
```

The message received in the Snowflake UI

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are after but you can use the VALIDATION_MODE parameter of the COPY INTO command to perform dry-runs of the files you intend to load, and then debug any issues from there. Have a look here: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#optional-parameters

Comment: Hi @MikeDonovan - Thanks for the info. We actually want it to fail if the location is incorrect.

Comment: Where do you run this? Do you have a programmatic process that runs this? You might want to perform that check (like in Python) before running that

Comment: Hi @Brock. We run it programmatically from the C# application. Right now, the checking of `o files processed` is not built-in to that application as there are chances that the prefix or folder doesn't have any files inside it